# Python/Django shell won't start

Tags: python, django, shell

One of the great features of Django is that you can open a python interpreter set-up for use with your project. This can be used to analyse objects in a database and allows any python commands to be executed on your project. I find it essential for Django development. It is invoked in the project directory using this command:

```
$ python manage.py shell
```

I have just started developing a new project and for some reason the shell does not work. I have had a look online for the error and not found anything. I would greatly appreciate any help on this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in 
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 362, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 303, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 195, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 222, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 29, in handle_noargs
    shell = IPython.Shell.IPShell(argv=[])
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Shell'
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Do you have ipython installed?  Is it in your `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: Oh, that's nice, is django integrated with ipython then?

Comment: @shylent, yes it is, in the sense that it will use IPython as the shell if it's installed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems like IPython is installed wrongly somehow. Try starting the shell with:

```
./manage.py shell --plain
```

to start the standard Python shell, rather than IPython. If that works, then trying removing IPython completely and reinstalling it.

Answer (score 7):

IPython 0.11 has a different API, for which a fix exists in the last Django versions.

For older Django versions, you can use IPython 0.10, which does work:

```
pip install ipython==0.10
```

Comment: down vote
 

That worked.

However when I started the shell, I got IOError: File'ipythonrc' not found in current or supplied directories:. Probably wrote the ipython 11 version over the existing and 10 no longer could read!?

running:

rm -rf ~/.ipython/

Seemed to fixit.

Comment: @brianray: that is possible, I can confirm that `rm -Rf ~/.ipython/` is a good fix here.

Comment: Thanks! I was exactly looking for a version of python that works with django 1.0.4

Comment: It 's wored for me to install  ipython (just defualt, newest not a specific version)
pip install ipython