# Django shell doesn't work?

Tags: python, django

When I start the django shell I got this memory error!
I'm on a shared host without root privileges. I can't install Ipython but I need the shell.

```
$ python manage.py shell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/django/core/management/base.py", line 218, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/django/core/management/base.py", line 347, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 26, in handle_noargs
    import IPython
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    __import__(name,glob,loc,[])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/Shell.py", line 30, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 555, in <module>
    _reset_cache()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 279, in _reset_cache
    CFUNCTYPE(c_int)(lambda: None)
MemoryError
```

Comment: You don't need root privileges to install Python packages. Setup a venv and install it all locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the --plain Option.

Maybe this answer can help you: [Python/Django shell won't start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078059/python-django-shell-wont-start?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the settings on your /tmp directory. Does is have the sticky bit set, too? If you do ls -ltrd /tmp, it should look similar to the following

`# ls -ltrd /tmp
drwxrwxrwt 6 root root 4096 Feb  5 16:43 /tmp`

You can also try re-mounting /tmp if it is specially mounted (you need to be root to do this). There was something wrong with my /tmp directory, so I unmounted it and re-created a new version of /tmp. Then the above error went away for my application.